# I always see a notification for a low quality post review but my queue is empty. Why does this happen?

Tags: bug

For some days now I always see a red notification dot on the review queues button:

[image]

But when I click on the "Low Quality Posts" tab, my queue is empty. I think this is because it's a question that I created or edited. After viewing the empty queue, the red dot disappears until I visit the site again at a later point in time. Is this a stack exchange bug?